# How to get average value of top n values and bottom n values for every value in a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

the easiest way to explain this should be an example.

Imagine following dataframe:

```
a  b 
1  5   
2  4
3  2
4  2
5  4
6  3
7  2
8  1
9  0
```

I want to be able to get the average of top 3 values and bottom 3 values for each value in column b.
so it should look like this

```
a  b   c
1  5   
2  4   
3  2
4  2  3.3
5  4  2.3
6  3  1.83
7  2  
8  1
9  0
```

any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand, what values are you averaging? which top 3 and which bot 3? How do you get  `3.3`, `2.3` and `1.83` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using some help from numpy: 
(df is your example dataframe)

```py
length = df.shape[0]   # Number of rows in the dataframe
windowSize = 3         # Since we are looking at top 3 and bottom 3 values 

for i in range(windowSize, length-windowSize):                   
    # Get the indexes (0-based) of the top 3 values 
    top3Idxs = np.arange(i - windowSize, i)
    bottom3Idxs = np.arange(i + 1, i + 1 + windowSize)
    
    # Get the values in column b at the proper indices
    top3Vals = df.b.to_numpy()[top3Idxs]
    bottom3Vals = df.b.to_numpy()[bottom3Idxs]
    
    # Find the average of the top3Vals and bottom3Vals
    avg = np.mean(np.concatenate((top3Vals, bottom3Vals)))
    
    # Set the average at the proper index in column c
    df.at[i, 'c'] = avg
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question or how you got the values in column 'c'. If you want the top and bottom averages of the two columns, that would be 4 separate values (whereas you only have 3 values in column 'c'). I'm also not sure if by top/bottom you mean highest/lowest 3 values in each column (since you say top 'n' values, I'm guessing not).

The top/bottom averages of col 'a' and col 'b' would just be this:

```
data = {'a': list(range(1,10)), 'b': [5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   4
2   3   2
3   4   2
4   5   4
5   6   3
6   7   2
7   8   1
8   9   0

n = 3

averages = {}
for col in df.columns:
    averages[col+'_bottom_avg'] = df[col][:n].mean()
    averages[col+'_top_avg'] = df[col][-n:].mean()

Output:

averages
{'a_bottom_avg': 2.0,
 'a_top_avg': 8.0,
 'b_bottom_avg': 3.6666666666666665,
 'b_top_avg': 1.0}
```

If you want the average of the top 3 max/min values, you can just sort the columns first:

```
averages = {}
for col in df.columns:
    averages[col+'_bottom_avg'] = df[col].sort_values()[:n].mean()
    averages[col+'_top_avg'] = df[col].sort_values()[-n:].mean()

Output:

averages
{'a_bottom_avg': 2.0,
 'a_top_avg': 8.0,
 'b_bottom_avg': 1.0,
 'b_top_avg': 4.333333333333333}
```

Apologies if I have completely misunderstood your question.